# Google Data Studio Regexp Replace formula - delete all characters after ? and #

Tags: regex, looker-studio, regexp-replace, re2

I have a dasbhoard in Google Data Studio

I'm trying to create a custom field and replace all the characters that are going after # and ? sing (of course them too). But this formula - i dont know why - does not work

I was trying this one

`REGEXP_REPLACE(Landing Page,'(#|\?)(.*)','')`

Could you please help?

Comment: If you want to keep the `?` or `#` you should use group 1 in the replacement `\\1` The pattern could be `([#?]).+`

Comment: Or, if you mean there are linebreaks, use `REGEXP_REPLACE(Landing Page,'(?s)[#?].*','')`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you tried `(#|\?)(.*)` caputures either `#` or `?` using a capturing group with an alternation `|` followed by capturing 0+ times any char in another capturing group.

But in the replacement there is an empty string specified, removing all that is matched.

---

You could make use of a character class `([#?])` in a capturing group to capture one of the listed.

To only do the replacement where there is something after the match, you could match 1+ times any character except a newline using `.+`

To remove what comes after the matched character, you could refer to the capturing group using `\\1` so that you keep the `#` or `?` and remove what is matched afterwards.

The pattern could look like:

```
([#?]).+
```